# How to access a lookup field through SOQL in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

3 Standard Objects: A, B, C

1. A has a field f1 lookup with B object.
2. B has a field f2 lookup with C object.
3. C has a field f3 which is a text.

How to access f3 field value through Object A?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A, B and C are standard objects, and f1, f2, f3 are standard fields; and all of them are API names, your SOQL query would look something like:

```
SELECT f1.f2.f3 FROM A
```

If A, B and C are custom objects, and f1, f2 and f3 are custom fields; and again all of them are API names, it would look like:

```
SELECT f1__r.f2__r.f3__c FROM A__c
```

Also remember to add some kind of `WHERE` or `LIMIT` clause to avoid hitting [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).

[More info on SOQL relationships.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)